# C++ Code Clarification Needed

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to understand what the code below says:

struct compare_pq;

```
struct compare_pq {
    bool operator() (Events *& a, Events *& b);
};

std::priority_queue<Events *, std::vector<Events *>, compare_pq> eventList;
```

i looked at what priority_queue is and how its declared but can't quit understand what `compare_pq` is doing in the priority_queue `eventList`. Also what does `operator()` do since i've never seen `*&` before and empty operator overloading `operator()`!

any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You should use the markdown code syntax rather than the HTML <code> tag because <code> does not enable syntax coloring, among other problems.

Answer (score 6):

`operator()` is the function-call operator.  It allows you to use an object of the class type as if it were a function, e.g.,

```
compare_pq my_comparator;
bool result = my_comparator(a, b);
```

Objects of class types that overload `operator()` are frequently called function objects or functors.

The third template parameter of `std::priority_queue` is for the comparison function.  By default, the priority queue sorts its elements using `std::less`, which applies `operator<` to two elements.  You can use any function (or function object) that takes two elements and returns a boolean indicating whether the first is smaller than the second.  "Smaller" in this case is a relative term:  the `top()` of the priority queue is the "largest" element currently in the queue.

In this case, you need to use a custom comparison function because the priority queue is storing pointers, so by default it would sort the elements by pointer value.  The custom comparator (probably) dereferences the pointers and performs some comparison on the pointed-to objects.

`Events*&` is just a reference to a pointer to an `Events` object.  It really doesn't need to be passed by reference.  Since it's just a pointer, it can be passed by value (e.g., `Events*`).  If you do choose for some reason to use a reference it should be a const reference.

Comment: +1: Since it's just a pointer, shouldn't it be passed by value?

Comment: Events*& refrence to a pointer to an object. Hrm can you please give an example on how it is typically used?

Comment: also why is a struct used to declare compare_pq?

Comment: A reference-to-pointer in C++ is analogous to C's pointer-to-pointer. It's there to allow you to change what the underlying pointer is pointing to. In the case of a comparator object it most definitely should be passed by value or by const-reference, because you probably don't want to change what the pointers point to -- only to read them. In fact, the `operator()()` should also be a `const` member, so it can work even on algorithms that take a `const`(-reference) function object.

Comment: @Billy:  Thanks; that's what I meant, but it was not at all clear.  @ke3pup:  A `struct` is the same thing as a `class` but its members and base classes are public by default instead of private.  @WilhelmTell:  Good point that the operator should be const (and good description of the reference--thanks).

Comment: To me, `bool operator() (const Events* a, const Events* b) const;` makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

*& is a reference to a pointer. It works like any other kind of reference. In less sophisticated C++ code you might see a double pointer (**) used.

compare_pq is a functor used to compare Event pointers. In this case, priority_queue would likely be instantiating a compare_pq whenever a comparison is needed.

```
Event * a = new Event();
Event * b = a;
compare_pq foo;
bool result = foo(a, b);
```

operator() is not empty. You're looking at a declaration. It must be defined somewhere else if it is to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer the question why a functor is used. It's just a guess of course, as I'm not the author of the code, but I saw discussions about it at least a few times and the consensus seems to be, that functors enable or at least make it easier to inline the comparison code.

Functors are structs (or classes) and in general are more flexible than regular functions because they can have some members, that store some state, which can be used by operator(). In this case this advantage isn't used, so the functor was most probably used to enable (or help) in inlining or just because the author was used to this common pattern.

Why would it help in inlining? Let's look at a simple example. Lets take `std::sort`

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp );
```

Imagine You want to sort `std::vector<int>` and You want to provide Your custom comparators.

```
struct MyStructComp1
{
    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const { /*...*/}
};

struct MyStructComp2
{
    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const { /*...*/}
};

bool myFunctComp1 (int lhs, int rhs) const { /*...*/}
bool myFunctComp2 (int lhs, int rhs) const { /*...*/}
```

Now You can use the `sort` temeplate in the following ways

```
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), MyStructComp1()); // 1
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), MyStructComp2()); // 2
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myFunctComp1);  // 3
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myFunctComp2);  // 4
```

Here are the function the compiler creates form the template

```
sort<vector<int>::iterator, MyStrucComp1> // 1
sort<vector<int>::iterator, MyStrucComp2> // 2
sort<vector<int>::iterator, bool (*) (int lhs, int rhs)> // 3, // 4
```

Since the Compare parameter in the sort template is a type, and functors are types, the compiler creates a different function for every functor supplied as a template argument. `sort<vector<int>::iterator, MyStrucComp1>` and
`sort<vector<int>::iterator, MyStrucComp2>` are two different functions. So when `sort<vector<int>::iterator, MyStrucComp1>` is created, it is known exactly what the comparing code is and the comparator can be simply inlined.

Functions `myFunctComp`1 and `myFunctComp2` however are of exactly the same type:
`bool (*) (int lhs, int rhs)` and the compiler creates one function `sort<vector<int>::iterator, bool (*) (int lhs, int rhs)>` for all comparing functions of type `bool (*) (int lhs, int rhs)`. I saw opinions, that inlining is possible anyway in this situation, but I have no idea how.

It is possible to create templates with a pointer to function as a template parameter as it's a compile time constant, but it's ugly and constants can't be deduced from the function arguments. For example if `sort` was defined as:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator,
bool (*comparer) (typename RandomAccessIterator::value_type, typename RandomAccessIterator::value_type)>
    void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) {/*   */}
```

You would have to call it like this

```
sort<std::vector<int>::iterator, myFunctComp1>(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

You would get a different sort for every comparing function, but functors are much more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for explaining , just out of curiosity how would the functor look if it wasn't inline?

Comment: The operator is inline if it's body is directly inside the class body or if explicitly marked with a keyword inline, when defined outside of the class. If it's just declared in the class definition and not marked as inline in the definition outside of the class definition, it is not inline, but I don't thing the compiler is forbiden to inline it, if it can. The inline keyword or definition in the class solves the problem with many definitions, but it's just a hint for the compiler, not a guarantee that inlining will actually take place.